# Unexpected useEffect behaviour

Tags: reactjs

I am making hangman game. When letter is clicked it should not be clickable any more.

Here' a simplified version on codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-cori-6b80q

In the sandbox, when letter is clicked it changes to "CLICKED!". Everything seems well here.

But in my project I get strange behavior.

AvailableLetter.js

```
const AvailableLetter = (props) => {

    const [clicked,setClicked]=useState(false);

    const setStuff = () => {
        setClicked(false); // If I delete this I get Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.
        props.setSolved();
    };
    useEffect( setStuff,[clicked] );

    if (clicked)         // IF CLICKED REMAINS TRUE, EVERY LETTER GETS PLAYED.
    {
        if (props.play())
        {
            props.correct();
        }
        else
        {
            props.incorrect();
        }
    }

    const disableLetter = () => {
        setClicked(true);
    };

    let letter=span onClick={disableLetter}>{props.alphabet}</span>;

    if(clicked)    // CODE NEVER GETS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    {
        letter = <span>{props.alphabet}</span>;
    }

    return (
        <Ax>                 // Ax is a high order class, just a wrapper
            {letter}
        </Ax>
    );
}
```

Letter remain clickable even after being clicked. This is not what I want.

Each letter is rendered by Letters.js which feeds in a-z and generates custom AvailableLetter.

```
const availableLetters = [ ...allLetters ].map(
        (alphabet,i) => {
            return (
                <AvailableLetter setSolved={props.setSolved} play={()=>playHandler(alphabet)} correct={()=>props.correct(alphabet)} incorrect={()=>props.incorrect(alphabet)} solution={props.solution} key={i} alphabet={alphabet} />
            );
        }
    );
```

So issues to be solved here are:

```
- Letters remain clickable even after a click
- If setClicked(false) is removed it causes an infinite loop
```

```
const setStuff = () => {
        setClicked(false);    // if removed causes infinite loop
        props.setSolved();
    };
```

All of this is strange because in the codesandbox I don't need to set clicked to false inside setEffect().

You can see all of the code here: https://github.com/gunitinug/hangmanerrors/tree/master/src
Please have a look at project code, it is not long.

Comment: IMO this is overcomplicated. I wouldn't use useEffect for this. Or have the clicked state live in the letter.

You can have an array of objects representing each letter and update the letter's clicked value when clicked. Keep that in a parent component along with what to do when the letter is clicked. Pass that data/functionality down as a prop.

If clicked, return the letter, if not show whatever you'll show when it hasn't been picked yet.

Comment: @ceckenrode thanks a bunch. i followed your advice and now it works 100%

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how `useEffect` works. Whenever the state changes, `useEffect` gets called and the handler (in your case `setStuff`) passed as a callback to `useEffect` gets executed.

So, `setStuff` keeps updating the state and `useEffect` keeps getting called continuously. Hence, you see the error `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded`.

Change your code as shown below:

```
const AvailableLetter = (props) => {

    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

    const setStuff = () => {
      if(clicked) {
        if (props.play()) {
          props.correct();
        }
        else {
          props.incorrect();
        }

        setClicked(false);
        props.setSolved();
      }
    };

    useEffect( setStuff, [clicked] );

    return (
        <Ax>
            <button onClick={() => setClicked(true)} disabled={clicked}>{props.alphabet}</button>
        </Ax>
    );
}
```

As mentioned in the comment posted on your question, this might not be the best approach but my code should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a structural problem, I had to delegate handler functions and state to the parent component Letters.js

I got to make it work silky smooth :p

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import AvailableLetter from './AvailableLetter/AvailableLetter';
import DisabledLetter from './DisabledLetter/DisabledLetter';
import classes from './Letters.module.css';

const Letters = (props) => {
    const [lettersMap, setLettersMap]=useState(
        {
            "a":false,"b":false,"c":false,"d":false,"e":false,"f":false,"g":false,"h":false,"i":false,"j":false,"k":false,"l":false,"m":false,"n":false,"o":false,"p":false,"q":false,"r":false,"s":false,"t":false,"u":false,"v":false,"w":false,"x":false,"y":false,"z":false
        }
    );

    const updateClickedHandler = (letter) => {
        setLettersMap(
            {
                ...lettersMap,[letter]:true
            }
        );
    };

    const playHandler = (alphabet) => {
        const solution = props.solution.split('');
        console.log(solution);

        if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
        {
            console.log('incorrect');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('correct');
            return true;
        }
    }

    const renderedLetters = Object.keys(lettersMap).map(
        (letter,i)=>{
          if (!lettersMap[letter])     //letter is not yet clicked
          {
            return (
                <AvailableLetter updateClicked={updateClickedHandler} setSolved={props.setSolved} play={()=>playHandler(letter)} correct={()=>props.correct(letter)} incorrect={()=>props.incorrect(letter)} solution={props.solution} key={i} alphabet={letter} />
            )
          }
          else                         //letter is clicked
          {
            return (
                <DisabledLetter alphabet={letter} />
            )
          }
        }
    );



    return (    
        <div className={classes.Letters}>
            <p>Solution: {props.solution}</p>
            <div className={classes.AvailableLetters}>
                {renderedLetters}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Letters;
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './AvailableLetter.module.css';
import Ax from '../../hoc/Ax';

const AvailableLetter = (props) => {

    const setStuff = () => {
      if (props.play()) {
        props.correct();
      }
      else {
        props.incorrect();
      }

      props.updateClicked(props.alphabet);
      props.setSolved();
    };

    return (
        <Ax>
          <span className={classes.AvailableLetter} onClick={setStuff}>{props.alphabet}</span>
        </Ax>
    );
}

export default AvailableLetter;
```

and finally, I added another component called DisabledLetter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './DisabledLetter.module.css';

const DisabledLetter = (props) => {
    return (
    <span className={classes.DisabledLetter} >{props.alphabet}</span>
    );
};

export default DisabledLetter;
```

You can view entire source here
https://github.com/gunitinug/hangmanclicked/tree/master/src
;)

Discovered an issue though, when game is solved I need to click one more letter for 'YOU WIN' message to display.

When I die 'GAME OVER' is displayed immediately.